# Can I use HTML5 tag in jsf(.xhtml)

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml, facelets

I want to use some HTML5 tag in jsf file, such as ,  and so on, but it doesn't work because the suffix of jsf file is .xhtml.
Is there any possible to use HTML5 tag in jsf file??

Comment: What is the `DOCTYPE` declaration on top of the file?

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work" in detail, because the argument of `.xhtml` suffix being the cause is complete nonsense. HTML5 works perfectly fine in any JSF version, including 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, is it the issue of file extension or the version of JSF that hinders you from using the HTML5 tag?

There are some HTML5 features the previous JSF components don’t support out of the box. You ma yuse a library like [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit).
If you are using JSF 2.2, it is already support HTML5.